# Can't connect Node.js with Docker MySQL database in GitHub actions

Tags: node.js, docker, github-actions

For a project I'm trying to use Node.js unit tests in GitHub actions.
But I'm having problems connecting the Node.js with my database running in docker (via GitHub).

This is my workflow:

```
name: Node.js CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     # Service containers to run with `runner-job`
    services:
      # Label used to access the service container
      biddify-product-database:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: robfontys/biddify-product-database:latest
        #
        ports:
          # Opens tcp port 6379 on the host and service container
          - 3306:3306
    timeout-minutes: 1      
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x, 14.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test
```

When I run the workflow this is the error:

[image: Github actions]

So my question is how to connect Node.js to the MySQL database? Is the IP address of the contrainer 127.0.0.1 (localhost)?

Comment: Have you tried using the service name as hostname? So instead of localhost yours would be `biddify-product-database`.

Comment: @LeadingMoominExpert Yes I already tried that, resulting in this ERROR: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN biddify-product-database

Comment: There is a comment about port 6379 in your code. Is your container actually listening on the 3306?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the Docker container to be fully started up, so you need to add a sleep for a sufficient amount of time. I found that 2 minutes is more than enough for small projects. Try to run the following:

```
    name: Node.js CI
    on:
      push:
        branches: [ master ]
      pull_request:
        branches: [ master ]
    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
         uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: docker-compose up -d biddify-product-database
    - name: Sleep for 120 seconds
      uses: jakejarvis/wait-action@master
      with:
        time: '120s'
    - run: npm test
```

Comment: Never use fixed delays on your automatizations. See Corey's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to solve this would be to use healthcheck. For example if the service that is taking a long time to get to a healthy state is mysql you can add a health check to that container

```
healthcheck:
  test: mysqladmin ping -h mysql --user=$$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 12s
  retries: 10
```

and then on your server add a dependency that the mysql service is in a healthy condition

```
depends_on:
  mysql:
     condition: service_healthy
```

This way when you bring up your stack it will wait until mysql is healthy, bring up the server and then detach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this code was only for a school project ;)